# $aH=Ha$ implies $a$ commutes with every element in H

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was trying to prove this question:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H \le G$. Let $a,b \in G$. Now, if $aH=Ha$ and
>   $bH=Hb$, then show that $(ab)H=H(ab)$.

It appears to me that if I can show that $a,b$ commutes with every element of $H$, then it is quite easy to show $(ab)H=H(ba)$.

However, how do I prove that $aH=Ha$ implies $a$ commutes with every element in $H$? Suppose $x\in H$ be arbitrary. Then $ax \in aH$ and $xa \in Ha$. Also by their equality, it follows that $xa \in aH$ and $ax \in Ha$. But does it necessarily mean $ax=xa$ in any of the cosets?

Comment: Let $G$ be non-Abelian and $H=G$...

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ were commuting with any elements of $H$ it would be true that $abH=Hab$ however you cannot prove that $aH=Ha$ implies $a$ commutes with every element in $H$ because the implication is false. Actually the proof is simple, I begin $(ab)H=a(bH)=a(Hb)=$...

Comment: @ClémentGuérin Thanks, I got confused because of this page: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~mstemper2/Math/Pinter/Chapter13E . He claims the above but doesn't prove it.

Comment: You are welcome, it is quite common for people knowing well the theory to be a little too quick in their argumentation when doing such fundamental material. My professor used to say "it is not a mistake from me, it is just to see if you are following!" The point is that by doing again the proof and realizing that there is a mistake you end up learning much more than with a correct proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean that. Given any $h_1\in H $, there exists  $h_2\in H $ such that $bh_1=h_2b $. There exists  $h_3\in H $ such such that  $ah_2=h_3a $. Then  $$abh_1=ah_2b=h_3ab. $$ As you can also do this backwards, you get  $abH=Hab $.

Answer (score 3):

We don't have $a$ commutes with every elements of $H$. But, we have the following statement:

If $A,B,C$ are *subsets* of a group $G$, then $(AB)C=A(BC)$. Here, $AB = \{ ab \in G| a \in A, b \in B \}$.(This fact is easy to prove by proving they have same elements form $abc$)

So,we have $(ab)H = a(bH)$(as above) $= a(Hb) = (aH)b = (Ha)b = H(ab)$ (use above statement twice.)